# Migration of tortoisesvn local repository to mac

Tags: macos, svn, tortoisesvn, smartsvn

I have been using Tortoise SVN in windows using a local repository(copy also available in dropbox). Now for sake of work I have to migrate to Mac OS. Tortoise SVN is unavailable for mac and hence I decided to use SmartSVN. I have copied the Tortoise repository to my mac system. However I am not sure how (If it is even possible) to checkout the project files using SmartSVN.

Also is it possible to browse the tortoise repository using smartsvn.

Please advice.

PS: I am new to Mac and not experienced with smartsvn.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just point SmartSVN to the repository using file:// access scheme. It doesn't matter whether it's TortoiseSVN, SmartSVN or a command-line client -- the repository itself is a regular Subversion repository and neither of these tool should have any issues accessing it.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that.